# Unable to send mail through amazon ses in python

Tags: python, amazon-ses, smtplib

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Some subject'
    msg['From'] = 'noreply@xyz.com'
    msg['Date'] = cur_date.isoformat(sep= ' ')
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(['super@xyz.com', 'other@xyz.com'])

    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    payload = "some generated payload message"
    part.set_payload(payload)
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    msg.attach(part)

    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port='587')
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login('user', 'psw')
    print("Sending mail..")
    s.sendmail('noreply@xyz.com', ['super@xyz.com', 'other@xyz.com'], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    print("Mail Sent")
```

I'm sending an email with attachment through python using amazon ses. I'm getting the following error -

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, 'Message rejected: Email address is not verified.')
```

My 'From' address is verified and email sending from other parts of code which are in JAVA are working with same set of email addresses. What am I missing as if I use 'smtp.gmail.com' and my credentials it works.

Comment: Take a raw network dump from SMTP traffic from a  working Java application and compare it to what Python does and spot the difference.